# phpmyadmin 404 not found ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04, server, virtualbox, apache2

I'm trying to get phpmyadmin up on my browser after installing ubuntu server 14.04 which works fine.  I can pull up the apache2 website with 10.0.2.15.  I installed webmin with not problems, and that works on 10.0.2.15:10000. The problem is phpmyadmin will not come up after installation, I believe it installed fine as not errors were showing upon `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`.  I notice that on the browser it has a 404 not found on port 80.  Is port 80 blocked in this case?  Should I set to NAT with port forwarding?  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$ ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-available:    
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 315 Jan 3 2014 charset.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 127 Aug 11 2014 javascript-common.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3224 Jan 3 2014 localized-error-pages.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 189 Jan 3 2014 other-vhosts-access-log.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2190 Jan 3 2014 security.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 455 Jan 7 2014 serve-cgi-bin.conf

$ ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-enabled    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Dec 6 11:13 charset.conf -> ../conf-available/charset.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Dec 6 11:45 javascript-common.conf -> ../conf-available/javascript-common.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Dec 6 11:13 localized-error-pages.conf -> ../conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Dec 6 11:13 other-vhosts-access-log.conf -> ../conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Dec 6 11:13 security.conf -> ../conf-available/security.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Dec 6 11:13 serve-cgi-bin.conf -> ../conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

Comment: A 404 indicates that it was able to connect to the server just fine, but what you requested was not found ("404 Not Found"). Can you post the output of `ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-available` and `ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-enabled` by editing your question?

Comment: Is there a way to cut and paste in virtualbox?

Comment: If you install virtualbox guest addons, the clipboard is shared.

Comment: This could be that I'm running 14.04 in virtualbox and not 13.04 which is I think what is supposed to be used.  Sorry if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

When you install `phpmyadmin`, you should be asked which server it should configure web access for:

[image]

If you select `apache2`, as shown in the image, a configuration file is added to `conf-available`:

```
 ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-available/
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  315 Jan  3  2014 charset.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3224 Jan  3  2014 localized-error-pages.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Jan  3  2014 other-vhosts-access-log.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Dec  7 00:14 phpmyadmin.conf -> ../../phpmyadmin/apache.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2190 Jan  3  2014 security.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  455 Jan  7  2014 serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

Since this file does not exist for your, I suggest you run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

And select `apache2` when prompted.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I thought I had selected apache2 just by highlighting that option and pressing enter, but it is important to set the asterisk with spacebar. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have a virtual host file set up for phpmyadmin within apache2/sites-available. You can just make a copy of 000-default and edit it with correct configuration then rename to phpmyadmin and run `a2ensite phpmyadmin`. Also ensure correct permissions are set to phpmyadmin directory. `service apache2 reload` for minor changes and restart for major changes, I prefer restart as it guarantees the changes will take effect.